# Installing SSL Certificate on Nodejs Webapp Server

Tags: node.js, windows, ssl, cloudflare

I have a webapp server based on nodejs installed on Windows Server 2016. I want to install an SSL Certificate on such server. I've generated a free SSL from Cloudflare but it downloaded a DER file. The person responsible for configuring the Webserver said he needs a .pfx and a passphrase in order to install the SSL Certificate. Is there a way to convert .der to .pfx with a passphrase, or is there any other way to do that for free or buy one at a very low cost,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom SSL certificate for you server, consider obtaining it directly from Let's Encrypt https://letsencrypt.org/.

Alternatively, you can use Cloudflare as a reverse proxy on top of your Node.js server that will add SSL automatically without a need to configure anything (other than creating a DNS record and checking "Cloudflare Proxy" (orange) checkbox. Then in your server settings, you would just configure firewall rules to allow connections only from Cloudflare IPs that can be found here — https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/.